# React Native: Rendering infinite number of pages (bi-directional swiping)

Tags: android, arrays, carousel, react-native

**Question**

How do people implement an infinite number of pages for you to swipe through dynamically?

**Details**

If an app renders a page for a day you can expect to swipe to the right for the previous day and to the left for the next day.

For example, the FitNotes app does this seemlessly:
[image: FitNotes app day view]

Swiping to the right/left is the same as pressing on button 5/6. and displays already rendered pages. At the same time new pages for the now adjacent days are rendered as well.

Initially, I thought that this is something you would do using a carousel e.g., using the [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/) library. I imagined something like the example below but rendering a page using state variables instead of an array of images.

[image: Example carousel from the react-native-snap-carousel library]

So, if I wanted to render a page with the date at the top, I would have an array as part of the state, for example:

```
carouselElements: [ '2019/01/21', '2019/01/22', '2019/01/23']
```

Fed into the carousel below, I would get back three pages each one with the date rendered at the top.

```
<Carousel
    ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
    data={this.props.carouselElements}
    renderItem={this.renderDay}
    sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
    itemWidth={sliderWidth}
    enableSnap 
    firstItem={1}
    initialNumToRender={3}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
    onBeforeSnapToItem={(index) => this.changeEvent(index)}
    useScrollView/>
```

**Problem 1: Infinitely growing array**

You can start at `Day X` and render the adjacent two days ahead of time.
If I swipe to the left, you access `Day X+1` and concat `Day X+2` to the end of the array and render that day as well.

The array becomes:
`[ 'Day X-1', 'Day X', 'Day X+1', 'Day X+2']`

For performance, I can keep checking the index against a 3 day window and only render the selected day and the adjacent two days. But the array will grow infinitely and your code is O(n) at best.

**Problem 2: Indexing**

**a) Prepending elements:**

You can start at `Day X` and and then swipe to the right. You are now showing `Day X-1`. You add `Day X-2` to the start of the array and render it to prepare for a second swipe to the right. The problem is you added an element at index 0. Your system is pointing at the state of index 0 when it changed from `Day X-1` to `Day X-2`, thus the page now shows `Day X-2` instead.

i.e., instead of moving back one day when you swiped to the right, you moved back 2 days with each swipe.

**b) Removing elements**

If I remove an element to keep the array small, everything shifts but the index remains the same. The index now points to a different element than the intended one in the array and this reflects in the rendered page before the index can be corrected.

**Thus my question:**
How do people implement dynamic page rendering ad infinitum with page swiping? It seems like a lot of apps have it and I can't find anyone talking about it.

---

#### Edits

EDIT 1: Added images with accompanying edits to explain my problem better.

EDIT 2: I have a working implementation with [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper/) that basically takes a massive array and only renders the batch of slides immediately adjacent to the displayed page.

```
<Swiper style={styles.wrapper} 
          showsButtons={false}
          index={currentDateIndex}
          loadMinimal={true}
          loadMinimalSize={1}
          showsPagination={false}
          loop={false}
          onIndexChanged={(index) => dispatch(changeSelectedDayByIndex(index))}
         >
          {dates.map((item) => 
              this.renderDay(item)
            )
          }
</Swiper>
```

However, the `dates.map` command imposes a large performance penalty at startup.

Edit 3:
Using a `slice` command on the dates array before mapping doesn't seem like an option because I'd be rendering during an existing state transition..

Comment: I feel you could do this with the help of server-side rendering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution is based on this `react-native-swiper` you mentioned.
This is a tricky solution that can work if caching is done properly.
It's based on the following assumptions:

- Given an ID, you can derive ID+1 and ID-1. (This is valid for dates)
- You can scroll left or right only by 1 frame(View).

The idea is to have a wrapper component around the `<Swiper>` to hold an state array with 3 IDs: current, left and right.

```
state = {
  pages: ["2", "3", "4"],
  key: 1
}
```

When you swipe left or right, you can derive the next or previous 3 IDs and call `setState`. The `render` method would call the local cached information to get the view attributes for this 3 IDs and render the new Screens.  The `<Swiper>` element always have to point to `index={1}` as initial param, and keep it this way.

```
const cache = {
  "0": "zero",
  "1": "one",
  "2": "two",
  "3": "three",
  "4": "four",
  "5": "five",
  "6": "six",
  "7": "seven",
  "8": "eight",
  "9": "nine",
  "10": "ten"
}

renderItem(item, idx) {
    const itemInt = parseInt(item)
    const style = itemInt % 2 == 0 ? styles.slide1 : styles.slide2
    return (
      <View style={style} key={idx}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{cache[item]}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

However, when you swipe, it will set the current index to 2 or 0. So in order to make it to always point to index 1 (again, because you shifted and reloaded), you have to force the `<Swiper>` element to reload. You can do that by setting its key attribute to be defined by a state variable that always changes. That's the tricky part.

```
onPageChanged(idx) {
    if (idx == 2) {
                                                 //deriving ID+1
      const newPages = this.state.pages.map(i => (parseInt(i)+1).toString())
      this.setState({pages: newPages, key: ((this.state.key+1)%2) })
    } else if (idx == 0) {
                                                 //deriving ID-1
      const newPages = this.state.pages.map(i => (parseInt(i)-1).toString())
      this.setState({pages: newPages, key: ((this.state.key+1)%2) })
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        index={1}
        key={this.state.key}
        style={styles.wrapper}
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        onIndexChanged={(index) => this.onPageChanged(index)}>
        {this.state.pages.map((item, idx) => this.renderItem(item, idx))}
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
```

Aside all that, you have to make sure to always have enough cached information for your IDs. If the cache access is getting close to end, make sure to request new data and delete some amount of cached data in the other direction.

Here's a [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/UsHQZkhb) for the App.js and a [GitHub](https://github.com/diogenesgg/react-native-swiper-ad-infinitum) project so you can test the whole idea.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just got around to testing your code and it works as intended :). Thank you for your complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting.

I think some changes in system design would also be needed. Let me try to give answer point by point.

**Problem 1: Infinitely growing array**
You don't have to use array here as I see your criteria to add swipe feature is based on date. You have to have date functions to subtract/add to current date and making call for the same to server. Once data is received you need to maintain user cache which will help you reduce the calls for you.

**OR** if you want to stick to the arrays only you have to load the `Date+-3` data on user entry only and keep it in the cache only (Or new DB is one way but that would include cost).

**Problem 2: Indexing
a) Prepending elements:**

This shouldn't be an issue when you are getting rid of arrays. You can work with states and single object should work for you.

**b) Removing elements**

Your removing of elements would be on the basis of date and not on index. So if you receive empty response for a date i.e. `Date-1` then make a call for `Date-2` and as you have limit of 3 days you can disable the swiping functionality on null response.

(**OR**
If you are dealing with array only then you have to have a cron job which will update the data for you)

Hope it helps, I can go more in deep details if you want.

Comment: Maybe im a bit to late but im facing a quite similiar issue. Im trying to create a calendar view where you can swipe between month views. Additional data is requested for current-1, current and current+1 month, so swiping in one direction would cause a list change like in the example above. I tried the code above with `react-native-swiper-flatlist` but cant get rid of flickering when updating the data/pages.